# Getting error message :You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6

Tags: 16.04, steam

I have 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. and I am getting the error message as described in the question. I tried previously recommended fixes but they didn't work. The steam was working properly a few days back.
It can also be a model specific problem, I have Acer Aspire E5 laptop.

Comment: Steam doesn't stop working - particularly with that errors - out of the blue. Are you trying to reinstall it? If so, install directly from the repositories: *sudo apt install steam*

Comment: Can you please specify the previously recommended fixes that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Run :

```
 sudo apt-get install '^libc6.*'
```

if doesn't work then:.

Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run the following commands:

For 64-bit Ubuntu:

```
 sudo ln -s /lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/libc.so.6
```

For 32-bit Ubuntu:

```
 sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
```

Comment: Thank you all , the problem got solved. I completely removed steam ie , deleted all the files and then reinstalled. Now it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the actual library but steam cannot find it try running `steam --reset`in a terminal and run `steam` again.